# I retrieve this type of error while getting photos from dropbox in android?

Tags: android, dropbox

[image]

When i trying to retrieving images from DropBox that time my device displays this type of message(in Toast form). What is the issue? if you have any idea related to it, than please Share with me. thanks

Comment: What code are you using to retrieve images from dropbox?

Comment: DropboxAPI<AndroidAuthSession> mApi;        mApi.getSession().startAuthentication(DBRoulette.this);     provided by dropbox

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the `access type` of your Dropbox app to <kbd>full Dropbox</kbd> instead of <kbd>app folder</kbd>. You have the this option when you register the app.

You may check your current access type at [Developer Apps](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/apps) page.